# Интерфейс или тип в typescript? Что использовать?

Tags: typescript

**Интерфейс:**

```
interface test {
    name: string;
}
```

**Тип:**

```
type test2 = {
    name: string,
}
```

**Перечень задач:**

1)Для создания переменной:

```
let test: test2 = {name: "test"};
```

2)Для создания объекта с экспортом:

```
const test = {
  name: "test",
}

export type {test};
export {test};
```

3)Для функций/классов.

Что использовать для этих пунктов, интерфейс или тип?

Comment: Вечером напишу подробный ответ

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вам нужно знать различие между типом и интерфейсом, чтобы уметь правильно выбрать и использовать.

### Книга - Эффективный TypeScript: 62 способа улучшить код.

Стр. 76

**ПРАВИЛО 13. Знайте разницу между type и interface**

Если вы хотите определить именованный тип в TypeScript, то у вас есть два варианта:

```
type TState = {  
    name: string;  
    capital: string;
}
```

Или интерфейс:

```
interface IState {  
    name: string;  
    capital: string;
}
```

(Также можно использовать class, но он относится к понятиям среды выполнения JavaScript и тоже вводит значение.

Что же вам следует использовать, `type` или `interface`? Граница между этими вариантами с течением времени размылась настолько, что в некоторых ситуациях можно использовать и то и другое. Обратите внимание на оставшиеся различия между ними и следуйте постоянству применения того или другого в конкретных ситуациях. Еще вам нужно знать, как прописать один и тот же тип при помощи любого из этих способов. Это поможет легче воспринимать код TypeScript, использующий их.

Сперва рассмотрим сходства: типы `State`, указанные выше, являются практически неотличимыми друг от друга. Если вы определите значение `IState` либо `TState` с дополнительным свойством, то ошибки в результате будут идентичными:

```
const wyoming: TState = {  
    name: 'Wyoming',  
    capital: 'Cheyenne',  
    population: 500_000
    // ~~~~~~~ Тип не может быть назначен для типа 'TState'.
    //         литерал может определять только известные
    //         свойства, а 'population' не существует в типе 
    //         'TState'.
};
```

Вы можете использовать сигнатуру индекса и для `interface`, и для `type`:

```
type TDict = { 
    [key: string]: string 
};

interface IDict {  
    [key: string]: string;
}
```

Также можно определить типы функций в обоих случаях:

```
type TFn = (x: number) => string; 

interface IFn {  
    (x: number): string;
}

const toStrT: TFn = x => '' + x; // ok
const toStrI: IFn = x => '' + x; // ok
```

Псевдоним типа выглядит более естественно для этого простейшего типа функции, но если тип будет иметь еще и свойства, тогда декларация будет выглядеть иначе:

```
type TFnWithProperties = {  
    (x: number): number;  
    prop: string;
}

interface IFnWithProperties {  
     (x: number): number;  
     prop: string;
}
```

Этот синтаксис легче запомнить, зная, что в JavaScript функции являются вызываемыми объектами.И псевдонимы типов, и интерфейсы могут быть обобщенными:

```
type TPair<T> = {  
    first: T;  
    second: T;
}

interface IPair<T> {  
    first: T;  
    second: T;
}
```

`interface` может расширять type   (с некоторыми оговорками, упомянутыми ниже) и наоборот:

```
interface IStateWithPop extends TState {  
    population: number;
}
type TStateWithPop = IState & { population: number; };
```

Снова типы оказались идентичными. Оговорка заключается в том, что `interface` не может расширять сложные типы вроде типов объединений. Если вам нужно именно это, придется использовать `type` и `&`. Класс может реализовывать как `interface`, так и простой тип:

```
class StateT implements TState {  
    name: string = '';  
    capital: string = '';
}

class StateI implements IState {  
    name: string = '';  
    capital: string = '';
}
```

Так в чем же отличия? Одно вы уже видели: существуют типы объединения, но не существует интерфейсов объединения:

```
type AorB = 'a' | 'b';
```

Расширение типов объединений может быть весьма полезно. Если у вас есть раздельные типы для переменных `Input` и `Output` и отображения из имени в переменную:

```
type Input = { /* ... */ };
type Output = { /* ... */ };

interface VariableMap {  
    [name: string]: Input | Output;
}
```

тогда может понадобиться тип, приписывающий переменной имя. Например:

```
type NamedVariable = (Input | Output) & { name: string };
```

Этот тип не может быть выражен через `interface`. В целом `Type` имеет больше возможностей, чем `interface`. Он может выступать в качестве объединения, а также пользоваться более продвинутыми возможностями вроде отображения или условных типов.Помимо этого, он может более ясно выражать кортежи и типы массивов:

```
type Pair = [number, number];
type StringList = string[];
type NamedNums = [string, ...number[]];
```

Вы можете выразить что-либо подобное кортежу, используя interface:

```
interface Tuple {  0: number;  1: number;  length: 2;}
const t: Tuple = [10, 20]; // ok
```

Но это неудобно и отбрасывает методы кортежа, такие как `concat`. Лучше использовать `type`.Тем не менее у `interface` есть некоторые возможности, отсутствующие у `type`. Одна из них — это то, что `interface` может быть дополнен. Возвращаясь к примеру со `State`, вы могли бы добавить поле population другим способом:

```
interface IState {  
    name: string;  
    capital: string; 
}

interface IState {  
    population: number;
}

const wyoming: IState = {  
    name: 'Wyoming',  
    capital: 'Cheyenne',  
    population: 500_000
}; // ok
```

Это называется объединением деклараций. Вы наверняка встречали его ранее. Главным образом оно используется с файлами деклараций типов. Для его поддержки уместно использовать `interface`, поскольку в декларациях типов могут быть пропуски, которые должны заполнять пользователи. TypeScript использует слияние, чтобы получать разные типы для разных версий стандартной библиотеки JavaScript. Интерфейс `Array`, к примеру, определен в `lib.es5.d.ts`. По умолчанию — это все, что вы получаете. Однако если вы добавите `ES2015` к записи `lib` вашего `tsconfig.json`, то `TypeScript` также включит `lib.es2015.d.ts`. Это добавляет (посредством слияния) еще один интерфейс `Array` с дополнительными методами вроде `find`, характерными для `ES2015`.

В итоге вы получаете общий тип `Array`, богатый методами. Слияние поддерживается в обычном коде так же, как декларации. Если же вам важно, чтобы никто не мог в дальнейшем дополнять тип, то используйте `type`. **Вернемся к вопросу выбора между `type` и `interface`**. Для сложных типов выбора у вас нет: необходимо использовать псевдоним типа. Но что насчет более простых типов объектов, которые могут быть представлены и другим путем? Чтобы ответить на этот вопрос, вам следует учитывать согласованность и возможное дополнение. Если вы работаете с кодом, который постоянно использует `interface`, то придерживайтесь `interface`. Если же в нем применяется `type`, используйте `type`.В проектах, не имеющих установленного стиля, вам следует поразмыслить над возможностью дополнения. Если вы опубликуете декларации типов для `API`, пользователям будет удобно вставлять новые поля через `interface` при изменении `API`. Однако для типа, который используется внутри проекта, слияние деклараций может оказаться ошибкой, поэтому отдайте предпочтение `type`.

---

Также советую прочитать:

**Книга - Профессиональный TypeScript. Разработка масштабируемых JavaScript-приложений**

Cтр 119.
Глава - **Интерфейсы**

Также хорошо описывает различие между типом и интерфейсом и что где использовать.

**Книга - TypeScript быстро**

Cтр. 56 Глава - **Базовые и пользовательские типы**

Описывает различие между классом, типом и интерфейсом.

Comment: очень хороший ответ. Lasna, рекомендации в конце ответа оставляют простор для задумчивости и колебаний, так что я упрощу до императива: всё что описывается как интерфейс - интерфейс, всё остальное (пересечения, объединения, pick, omit, keyof Enum и т.п.) - типы. кажется сейчас все так делают

Comment: nörbörnën, А если мне необходимо объявить объект с константами, или, скажем... объект с учетными данными для подключения к базе данных. Это "тип", верно?

Comment: @Lasna1 объект с константами это - 'as const'. а вот для манипуляций с ним пригодится type. [пример](https://pastebin.com/UQchxnaM). объект с настройками подключения db, это - 1) [интерфейс](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/master/packages/pg-connection-string/index.d.ts) для описания такого объекта 2) сам объект

Comment: interface https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/driver/postgres/PostgresConnectionOptions.ts, type https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/connection/ConnectionOptions.ts#L25